# Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT) in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //code
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    while(test--)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length() - 2; j++)
        {
           if (input.substr(j, 3) == "gfg")
           {
                count +=1;
           }
        }
        if (count > 0)
        {
            cout << count << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << -1 << endl;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code shows Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT) while submitting in Geeks for Geeks while runs perfectly on the local computer and even works perfectly on various online compilers. Can't figure out the problem. Can someone help?

Comment: Off-topic but `if(count>0)` and `if(count)` is same.

Comment: @VinaySomawat I beg to differ. What if `count` is incremented enough times that it overflows its capacity? As a signed int, it will turn into a negative number. So, no, it is not the same, as unlikely as it is to happen.

Comment: @SirDarius Yes, You're right!

Comment: @VinaySomawat No, it isn't.

Comment: @SirDarius At least until c++17, overflowing an `int` is *not* guaranteed to turn into a negative number. It's just UB, so the check *is* equivalent.

Comment: I was just saying in reference to length of string. Coz it won't overflow in this case.

Comment: @cigien Fair enough! It's important to mention that integer overflow is a pretty important source of bugs though, and it shouldn't be overlooked.

Comment: @cigien • C++17 (or was is C++20?  P0907r1 is C++20 and q.v. N2218) made signed int 2's complement, but did it also change signed int overflow from undefined behavior to defined behavior?

Comment: @Eljay I'm not entirely sure what exactly changed in c++20 in this regard. I just know that till  (and including) c++17, overflow is UB.

Comment: @Eljay: It’s C++20, but nothing changed about overflow (except for shifting).  It did remove implementation permission to have non-modular behavior when *converting* from unsigned to signed.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what happens when `input` has fewer than two characters.

`input.length()` is an unsigned quantity, so `input.length() - 2` then would wrap around to an astronomically large number.

`input.substr(j, 3)` isn't good when `j` is an astronomically large number: [it throws the exception `std::out_of_range`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.substr#1); since you're not catching this exception, your program terminates.

These contests test to see whether you cover all your possible input domains, especially edge cases. Be sure to consider them when you write your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, the corner case. :P

Comment: Thanks a lot! I mulled over past 2 days, now saw what I was missing- `input.length()` is an unsigned quantity